# Oracle Query to get single result depending on values in result set

Tags: sql, oracle, case, common-table-expression

```
WITH T1 AS SELECT DISTINCT(DETAILS) FROM ( SELECT STATUS, PREREQUISITE_NM, 
    (case  when (STATUS='Completed' ) then 'Completed'
    when (STATUS='Pending' ) then 'Pending'
    when (STATUS='Failed' and PREREQUISITE_NM = 'Y') then 'Failed'
    when (STATUS='Failed' and PREREQUISITE_NM = 'N') then 'Completed'
    end )DETAILS FROM TABLE_LIST WHERE ID=1))
    T2 AS ( SELECT DETAILS FROM T1)
```

**Result 1 :**
Pending
Failed
Completed.
**Result 2:**
Failed
Completed.

In above Query we see the different result set as per data available. I want to write a query in T2 Block which should give Output as :

1. for Pending/Failed/Completed : should give Pending as output.
2. For Failed/Completed : should give Failed as Output.
   Is it possible to achieve this through query without using PL SQL block. like using WITH clause?

I can explain my aim such as

*Lets say T1 Block is giving me result as three rows Pending,Failed, Completed then I want Pending as a Output value. If T1 Block is giving me result as Failed, Completed then I want to Failed as Output value. If T1 block is giving only Completed then Completed will be considered as a output value.*

Comment: do you want both results at the same time ??

Comment: Lets say T1 Block is giving me result as three rows Pending,Failed, Completed then I want  Pending as a Output value.
If T1 Block is giving me result as Failed, Completed then I want to Failed as Output value. 
If T1 block is giving only Completed then Completed will be considered as a output value.

Comment: I post an answer, please follow up there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` Analytic function to bring those status values in alphabetical order descendingly which would suite your need :

```
WITH T1 AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT (CASE
         WHEN (STATUS = 'Failed' ) THEN
           CASE WHEN PREREQUISITE_NM = 'Y' THEN 'Failed' 
                WHEN PREREQUISITE_NM = 'N' THEN 'Completed' 
           END 
         ELSE 
           STATUS 
         END) AS details
  FROM TABLE_LIST
 WHERE ID = 1
), T2 AS
(
 SELECT T1.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY details DESC) AS rn
   FROM T1
 )   
SELECT details
  FROM T2
 WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  But as I mentioned I want to return only one value. Either Pending or Failed or completed depending upon the values we get in Query Output.

Comment: Thank you Very much. Query is working with the available statuses.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Roberto and Barbaros Ozhan, Both Answers were useful.Posting another way shared by one of my colleague.

```
WITH T1 AS (
SELECT
DISTINCT(DETAILS) 
FROM (
  SELECT STATUS, PREREQUISITE_NM, 
 (
CASE 
WHEN (STATUS = 'Failed' ) THEN
           CASE WHEN PREREQUISITE_NM = 'Y' THEN 'Failed' 
                WHEN PREREQUISITE_NM = 'N' THEN 'Completed' 
           END 
         ELSE 
           STATUS
           END
)DETAILS FROM TABLE_lIST WHERE ID=1)
),
T2 AS
(
SELECT CASE 
WHEN EXISTS
( SELECT DETAILS FROM  T1 where DETAILS='Pending' )
THEN 'Pending'  
WHEN EXISTS
( SELECT DETAILS FROM T1 WHERE DETAILS='InProgress' )
THEN 'InProgress'  
WHEN EXISTS
(SELECT DETAILS FROM T1 where DETAILS='Failed' )
THEN 'Failed'  
ELSE 'Completed' END  as DETAILS from DUAL 
                 )SELECT * FROM T2
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments, I came up with this solution, that perhaps is not the best, but at the end gives the output you expect , based on that what you actually want is to transpose the rows produced in t1 to columns in t2

I used my own test, please be aware to replace the columns or modify whatever is necessary to adapt it to your own query

```
SQL> desc my_test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 C1                                                 NUMBER
 C2                                                 VARCHAR2(20)
 C3                                                 VARCHAR2(1)

SQL> select * from my_test ;

        C1 C2                   C3
---------- -------------------- -
         1 Failed               Y
         2 Completed            Y
         1 Pending              Y
         1 Pending              N

SQL>
```

So, If just got the first part of my query

```
SQL> WITH T1 AS (
     SELECT DISTINCT c2 FROM ( SELECT c1,c2,
     case  when c2='Completed'  then 'Completed'
           when c2='Pending'    then 'Pending'
           when c2='Failed' and c3 = 'Y' then 'Failed'
           when c2='Failed' and c3 = 'N' then 'Completed'
           else c2
           end FROM my_test WHERE c1=1
                 ) )
select trim ( completed || ' ' || failed || ' ' || pending ) as result
from
(
select * from t1 pivot ( max(c2) for c2 in ( 'Completed' as Completed, 'Failed' as Failed, 'Pending' as Pending ) )
)
/  9   10   11   12   13   14   15

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------
Failed Pending
```

Now I only need to build a case over that result ( modify it to your own requirements )

```
SQL> WITH T1 AS (
            SELECT DISTINCT c2 FROM ( SELECT c1,c2,
                                                                                        case  when c2='Completed'  then 'Completed'
                                                  when c2='Pending'    then 'Pending'
                                                  when c2='Failed' and c3 = 'Y' then 'Failed'
                                                  when c2='Failed' and c3 = 'N' then 'Completed'
                                                                                        else c2
                                                                                        end FROM my_test WHERE c1=1
                 ) ) 
select 
case when result = 'Completed Failed Pending' then 'Pending' 
     when result = 'Completed Failed'         then 'Failed' 
     when result = 'Failed Pending'           then 'Failed' -- I guess
     when result = 'Completed Pending'        then 'Pending' -- I guess
end as output 
from (       
select trim ( completed || ' ' || failed || ' ' || pending ) as result 
from 
(                
select * from t1 pivot ( max(c2) for c2 in ( 'Completed' as Completed, 'Failed' as Failed, 'Pending' as Pending ) )
)
)
/

OUTPUT
-------
Failed

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you very Much. I will try the given solution and will update you.